# redux-form not showing errors

Tags: redux, jsx, redux-form, react-props

In my `redux-form` I'm having troubles showing the errors back to the form,

here's my form:

```jsx
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {
  registerUser,
  signOutUser
} from "../../actions/redux-token-auth-config";
import { Field, reduxForm, SubmissionError } from "redux-form";

import { FormDiv, SubmitButton, Title, Working } from "./styles";

const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) =>
  <div>
    <label>
      {label}
    </label>
    <div>
      <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
      {touched &&
        error &&
        <span>
          {error}
        </span>}
    </div>
  </div>;

const errorsFrom = response => response.response.data;

const signUp = (data, dispatch, props) => {
  return dispatch(props.registerUser(data))
    .then(response => dispatch(signOutUser(data)))
    .catch(response => {
      throw new SubmissionError(errorsFrom(response));
    });
};

const SignUp = props => {
  const { error, handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <FormDiv>
      <Title>subscribe</Title>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(signUp)}>
        <Field
          name="email"
          component={renderField}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email"
          label="Email"
        />
        <br />
        <Field
          name="password"
          component={renderField}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
          label="Password"
        />
        <br />
        <Field
          name="passwordConfirmation"
          component={renderField}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          label="Confirm Password"
        />
        <br />
        {error &&
          <strong>
            {error}
          </strong>}
        <SubmitButton type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
          Sign Up
        </SubmitButton>
        {submitting && <Working />}
      </form>
    </FormDiv>
  );
};

const ReduxFormSignUp = reduxForm({
  form: "signup"
})(SignUp);

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    error:
      state.form.signup && state.form.signup.submitErrors
        ? state.form.signup.submitErrors.errors
        : null
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    registerUser
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReduxFormSignUp);
```

After submitting I get some errors in my redux state:

[image: redux state]

but for some reason they fail to be passed back in the props. so my props contain `handleSubmit, pristine, submitting` but no `error` prop. Regardless whether I use my `mapStateToProps` or not

### Update

There seems to be an incongruence between the documentation and the library, I see no reference to passing errors to fields in here https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/blob/master/src/createField.js, as it's described here: https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/field.md/#usage

Similarly here: https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/docs/api/reduxform.md/ I see no references to passing error prop to the wrapped component. But I'm seeing so many examples where I should expect an `error` prop passed by `reduxForm`.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Each field error is passed to the Field and the generic error (`_`) is passed to the form. I think your code should work. Are the fields touched?

Comment: They are touched, and no errors are passed, I'm currently working it around passing errors manually. with the `mapStateToProps` and then to fields via: `errors['fieldName']`, quite a pain. possibly it's worth mentioning I'm using:     "redux-token-auth": "^0.19.0",

Comment: Can you create a small example showing this behaviour (codesandbox)?